# Squid doesn't cache with Kerberos auth

Tags: squid, kerberos

I am using a squid proxy with kerberos auth. Everything works great for months now, but my only problem is, that squid isn't caching anything!
As soon as I switch to NTLM auth, squid is caching, so I don't think, that it's a squid config problem. Is caching with kerberos auth generally not working?